# SSRS Report Viewer - Multi Select Parameter Issue

Tags: asp.net, reporting-services, reportviewer, multi-select

I am displaying a SSRS reportviewer control in my ASPNET web page. I am using report processing. It works fine for ordinary parameters in the reportviewer but acts strange for multi select parameters. If I click a multiselect parameter, I can see the list flash for a second and then disappear. It does this each time I click it.

Anyone have a solution to stop this flash and disappearance that would allow me to pick from a selection of parameter?

I already tried turning on IE8 compatibility mode, but no luck.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

```
    // Set the processing mode for the ReportViewer to Remote
    reportViewer.ProcessingMode = Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ProcessingMode.Remote;

    Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ServerReport serverReport = reportViewer.ServerReport;

    // Set the report server URL and report path
    string reportURL = string.Empty;
    switch (ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Environment"].ToUpper())
    {
        case "TEST":
            reportURL = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["testURL"];
            break;
        case "STAGE":
            reportURL = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["stageURL"];
            break;
        case "PROD":
            reportURL = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["prodURL"];
            break;
        default:
            this.lblMessage.Text = "Environment not found.";
            return;
    }
    serverReport.ReportServerUrl = new Uri(reportURL);
    serverReport.ReportPath = Path.Combine(ConfigManager.ReportingService.BaseReportPath, reportName);
```

Comment: Can you show us some code as to how and where you are setting the parameters and how you're calling the report viewer?

Comment: The parameters are set in SSRS report itself with the help of Dataset.

Answer (score 0):

I have this same error in ssrs 2019.  If my report contains a lot of parameters, causing a scroll bar to display them all, the only time I get the parameter to fail is when it is at the bottom of the list / bottom of the scrollbar display area.  If I simply move that parameter up higher in the list, it then works and the ones moved to the bottom of the list then stop working.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31182270)